# Macbook has issue -1008F when recovery from Internet

Tags: macos, recovery, internet-recovery

I have a problem with my MacBook, after erasing the SSD hard disk, I try to reinstall it by Utility and had a problem like the image below.

[image]

It stuck on the step because “INIT transmit failed”

Then, I try to reinstall my recovery from the internet and got a problem like that.
[image]

Does anyone know the -1008F meaning? please help.

**Solved**:

The problem happened again to me last month when I tried to reinstall my Mac from the Internet. I tried it many times, but did not succeed, I suffered on the internet and found that I still not remove the MacBook from iCloud. I tried and succeeded, so I think if anyone has the same problem as me, you should follow my way first.

Comment: Can you not restore from a backup? Erasing the disk is rarely necessary for a software problem.

Comment: I don't have a backup, and I did it many times in the past so I think everything will be okay if I do it again.

Answer (score 0):

What's your connexion mode? Ethernet, wifi? Have you try a Reset SMC, Reset NVRAM then retry?
Else, read this link : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206989

Comment: Thank you, error -1008F is gone, but another issue happened. Error -2003F. I looking for it on the internet and found it: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4382185?answerId=23620636022#23620636022